# callkit incoming call voice issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, callkit

I am implementing a callkit with pushkit in my one of the voip application.In ios 10.1 i was able to receive a incoming call audio.
but now updated a mobile to ios 10.2.1. after that incoming calls not able to hear a audio.
I need a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set audio session params b4 calling reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID

Here is a reference

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64544

Comment: Thank you dmitryfeld .actual issue in pjsip. i have updated into pjsip 2.6.it is working now.